# Accessing folder which are one level up from root folder (php)

Tags: php, directory, root, parent

I have  a "domain.com" which have folders 'user1' & 'sub'. 
Now i have a subdomain "m.domain.com", as this subdomain has root folder 'domain.com/sub'.
There is a file in root folder of subdomain  i.e 'm.domain.com/index.php'
I want to change the name of 'user1' to 'user2' by using 'm.domain.com/index.php'.

how can i access the parent folder of root i.e.
using "m.domain.com/index.php" accessing "domain.com/".

Comment: Where's the code? What server? Where's the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, URL `m.domain.com/index.php` points to file `domain.com/sub/index.php`. So if you want to access files from main domain from index.php on the subdomain, you would use relative path starting with `../`

Example: in file `domain.com/sub/index.php` (which translates to URL `m.domain.com/index.php`), I want to include file `library.php` from folder *user1* of the main domain. I use:

`include './../user1/library.php'; # the dot at the beginning denotes the current directory`

Comment: as the root of subdomain "m.domain.com" is "domain.com/sub".
so i am currently at 'm.domain.com/index.php" and i want to access one level up from root of "m.domain.com" i.e.' user1'

means: i want to take control on 'user1' from 'm.domain.com/index.php'

Comment: What do you mean by _access_? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to change the name of folder 'user1' by using 'm.domain.com/index.php'

as u can assume that 'm.domain.com/index.php' is holding the code to change the name of folder.

currently i am at "m.domain.com/index.php" and i want to go one level up from root of "m.domain.com" and change name of 'user1'.

Comment: Change name of _user1_ to what?

Comment: change from user1 to user2

Comment: Ok, change the name as in _rename the folder_? That would be `rename('./../user1', './../user2');` (placed info `domain.com/sub/index.php`)

Comment: sir i want to clear one thing, can i go one level up from root of subdomain.
means: "m.domain.com" has root of "domain.com/sub".
so can i go one level up of subdomain from "m.domain.com/index.php" and change user1's name

Answer (score 0):

If access allowed by server configuration you can use relative path.

```
rename(__DIR__ . '/../user1', __DIR__ . '/../user2');
```